# How to use trim function in join condition.?

Tags: sql, split, hive, trim

I have a dataset and in one of the columns  I have values like `'1-M3 [J]'` and `'1 - M3 [J]'`.  Both are same values but a space is added.Data is inconsistent in this case .

I used:

```
Split(column,'[-]')[0]
```

Which will give value 1 only one time .

`Split(column,'[ - ]')[0]` which will give only 1 value .

I am expecting both values to be retrieved, I request your help on this, use trim on Join condition?

Expected output is : 1,1

Comment: Please read and follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi - it is very unclear from your question what you are trying to achieve. Please update your question with example(s) of what you issue is and what you want the result to be. Providing details of a solution (using split) that doesn't work doesn't really help anyone. If you are just trying to make "1 - M3 [J]" = "1-M3 [J]" then just use REPLACE(column1, " - ", "-")

Comment: Clean your data with an UPDATE statement and then run the query. Don't clean data during a join, it's massively inefficient, and prevents the ability to use indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `REPLACE` to replace extra spaces with blank '' and then use it in join.

```
REPLACE(Column1, " ", "")
```

Comment: No I don't need to replace .I need the value 1 only in my Output....and I will use it in join..

Comment: can you not `substr(col,1,1)` ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following function block :

```
import re
data = ['1-M3[J]', '1-M3[J]']
number = []
for item in data:
    match = re.findall(r'\d+', item)
    if match:
        number.extend(match)
number = [int(num) for num in number]
print(number)
```

Comment: In hive, not python

Comment: oh okay, sorry not so good in hive